# Infinite dihedral group isomorphic to semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How would I show that the infinite dihedral group ($\{x,y\mid x^2=y^2=1\}$) is isomorphic to the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$ is generated by an element of infinite order $a$ and an element of order two $b$ satisfying the relation $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$. Try to find two elements of $\langle x,y\mid x^2,y^2\rangle$ with the same properties which also generate the whole group. Then you can establish an isomorphism.

Comment: $xy\mapsto a$, $x\mapsto b$?

Comment: @user384354 Yep.

Comment: Would this similarly extend to finding an isomorphism from $D_{n}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?